# My infix is what my suffix do

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

- My prefix tells things that's true.
- My suffix if famous will have fans.
- My infix is what my suffix do.
- My whole an element of the plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> FACTOR

> Prefix FACT

> Suffix ACTOR

> Infix ACT

> Whole FACTOR